# Recorrer texto en perl cogiendo lo que me interesa

Tags: split, perl, jython

Digamos que tengo el siguiente texto en perl, que es la salida de otro script, aunque se vea que son listas separadas por ";" en realidad es todo un unico texto, y tendría que, en perl, iterar el texto y pintar el contenido de cada lista.

```
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node Dmgr01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
['dmgr', 'DeploymentManager', '141', 'STARTED', 'Linux', '268369920', '67944496', 5]
;
['nodeagent', 'NodeAgent', '452', 'STARTED', 'Linux', '78839808', '16669256', 0]
;
['server', 'ManagedProcess', '1193', 'STARTED', 'Linux', '99352576', '29211936', '0', '0', 1]
;
['server2', 'ManagedProcess', '1232', 'STARTED', 'Linux', '94633984', '19410816', '0', '0', 1]
;
['server5', 'ManagedProcess', '1313', 'STARTED', 'Linux', '95485952', '20925528', '0', '0', 1]
;
```

Me valdria por ejemplo, crear una lista en perl con el contenido de cada una y luego pintarlo, supongo que esto podría hacerlo con split con la ; que esta puesta por eso, pero como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer tanto con split() o con una expresión regular, procesando cada línea.

Este es un ejemplo con split(). El resultado es una lista de listas de valores.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @res;

while (<>) {
    if (/\[(.+?)\]/) {                          # si la línea tiene corchetes

        my @columnas = split /\s*,\s*/, $1;     # dividimos por comas y espacios

        # filtramos las comillas
        @columnas = map { /^'(.+)'$/ ? $1 : $_ } @columnas;

        push @res, [ @columnas ];               # una fila más
    }
}

#use Data::Printer;
#p @res;
```

Esta es una posible solución con expresión regular:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
use strict;
use warnings;

my @res;

while (<>) {
    my @columnas;

    #print;
    while (/\[?'?(.+?)'?[,\]]\s*'?/g) {   # buscamos algo entre comas
                                          # pero sin comillas ni comas ni corchetes
        push @columnas, $1;               # y lo guardamos
    }

    if (@columnas) {                      # si encontramos algo
        #print "@columnas\n";
        push @res, [ @columnas ];         # lo guardamos como una fila más
    }
}

#use Data::Printer;
#p @res;
```

De todas maneras, el patrón de búsqueda es muy dependiente del formato de entrada. Si cambia ese formato, esta solución dejará de funcionar. split() es más robusto, en ese sentido.

Hay cientos de ejemplos más en el foro de Perl en Español.